# Virtualhost Serveralias does not display pictures

Tags: apache2

I added a virtual host to apache2 on my new Ubuntu 11.10 serverbox. 
Works fine for all the websites called by the plain domainname.

But adding a serveralias like 'ServerAlias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com' to the sites enabled virtualhost file, all the websites-pictures jpg, gif etc are not displayed in the browser calling the aliased website www.mydomain.com.

Clearly there is some difference between plain domainname mydomain.com and aliased domainnames like www.mydomain.com, but cannot asses which directive is causing this behaviour not displaying pictures in the aliased websites.

Where and which apache2 directive I have to add/skip in order to display pictures in aliased websites ?

Comment: Can we see the Apache config file? ("ServerAlias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com" does not look right, but there's more a person would want to see)

Answer (score 1):

That did the trick: "serveralias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com" deleted and replaced by "serveralias www.domain.com".
As simple as that :)

Fred aka Cheeseburger